# What is a faster version of this code instead of the double for-loop (python)?

Tags: python, algorithm

When I hand this code in on a site (from my university) that corrects it, it is too long for its standards.
Here is the code:

```
def pangram(String):
    import string
    alfabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    interpunctie = string.punctuation + "’" + "123456789"
    String = String.lower()
    string_1 = ""
    for char in String:                    
        if not char in interpunctie:
            string_1 += char
    string_1 = string_1.replace(" ", "")    
    List = list(string_1)
    List.sort()                            
    list_2 = []
    for index, char in enumerate(List):     
        if not List[index] == 0:
            if not (char == List[index - 1]):
                list_2.append(char)
    return list_2 == alfabet              

def venster(tekst):
    pangram_gevonden = False
    if pangram(tekst) == False: 
        return None
    for lengte in range(26, len(tekst)):
        if pangram_gevonden == True:
            break
        for n in range(0, len(tekst) - lengte):
            if pangram(tekst[n:lengte+n]):
                kortste_pangram = tekst[n:lengte+n]
                pangram_gevonden = True
                break
    return kortste_pangram
```

So the first function (pangram) is fine and it determines whether or not a given string is a pangram: it contains all the letters of the alphabet at least once.

The second function checks whether or not the string(usually a longer tekst) is a pangram or not and if it is, it returns the shortest possible pangram within that tekst (even if that's not correct English). If there are two pangrams with the same length: the most left one is returned.

For this second function I used a double for loop: The first one determines the length of the string that's being checked (26 - len(string)) and the second one uses this length to go through the string at each possible point to check if it is a pangram. Once the shortest (and most left) pangram is found, it breaks out of both of the for loops.

However this (apparantly) still takes too long. So i wonder if anyone knew a faster way of tackling this second function. It doesn't necessarily have to be with a for loop.

Thanks in advance

Lucas

Comment: The button for code formatting is the `{}` in the editor. You've formatted this all as quotes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  The main problems for me is that you've included a *lot* of superfluous code, and have shown no progress on the improvement you want.

Comment: I also tried running your code: it appears to produce no output.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll look into editing my post and try to remove as much of the unnecessary code as possible;

Comment: The code returns None if there is no pangram found in the string. Maybe that's what you mean? When I run it, it does correctly give the string it's supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map `{letter; int}` and `activecount` counter.
Make two indexes `left` and `right`, set them in 0.

Move `right` index.
If `l=s[right]` is letter, increment value for map key `l`.
If value becomes non-zero -  increment `activecount`.
Continue until `activecount` reaches 26

Now move `left` index.
If `l=s[left]` is letter, decrement value for map key `l`.
If value becomes zero - decrement `activecount` and stop.

Start moving `right` index again and so on.

Minimal difference between `left` and `right` while
`activecount==26` corresponds to the shortest pangram.

Algorithm is linear.

Example code for string containing only lower letters from alphabet 'abcd'. Returns length of the shortest substring that contains all letters from `abcd`. Does not check for valid chars, is not thoroughly tested.

```
import string
def findpangram(s):
    alfabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    map = dict(zip(alfabet, [0]*len(alfabet)))
    left = 0
    right = 0
    ac = 0
    minlen = 100000

    while left < len(s):

        while right < len(s):
            l = s[right]
            c = map[l]
            map[l] = c + 1
            right += 1
            if c==0:
                ac+=1
                if ac == 4:
                    break
        if ac < 4:
            break
        if right - left < minlen:
            minlen = right - left

        while left < right:
            l = s[left]
            c = map[l]
            map[l] = c - 1
            left += 1
            if c==1:
                ac-=1
                break

        if right - left + 2 < minlen:
            minlen = right - left + 1
    return minlen

print(findpangram("acacdbcca"))
```

Comment: Maybe I forgot to add though that I am only a beginning programmer so I don't know what a map is or how it works. Would you mind maybe transmitting some of this into code?

Comment: map is dict - pairs of key-value - in-built data structure in Python. I'll make quick code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! By the way, the names of the variables can be whatever, they don't have to correspond to my code.

Comment: Yes of course, I don't mean to make it easy for myself. It's just that I have only been programming for a couple of weeks. I read a book and am now learning about lists and tuples.