# Minimum Window Substring in Swift

Tags: swift, algorithm, data-structures

I am trying to learn swift by solving interview questions. One of the question that I am trying to solve is as follows.

**Given a string S and a string T, find the minimum window in S which will contain all the characters in T in complexity O(n).**

```
Example:

Input: S = "ADOBECODEBANC", T = "ABC"
Output: "BANC"
```

My implementation is as follows which holds `t` string characters and its corresponding index retrieved from `s`.

```
func minimumWindowSubstring(_ s: String, _ t: String) -> String{

    let sChar = [Character](s)
    let tChar = [Character](t)

    var indexTemp = [[Character:Int]()]

    for tc in tChar
    {
        for (j, sc) in sChar.enumerated()
        {
            if sc == tc
            {
                indexTemp.append([tc:j])
            }
        }
    }

    return ""
}
```

what I have in indexTemp array is as follows

[image]

Now I wonder how could I able to use this array to find the minimumwindow, I stuck.

Comment: Answer to alike question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52995516/844416

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was an interesting problem so I gave it a shot. Instead of using a dictionary I used a simple class to store the range of characters found, as well as a `String` that stores which characters haven't been found.

It only goes through the main string once, so it should be O(n).

You can run this in the playground.

(I know you wanted help in fixing your code and my answer doesn't do that, but I'm hoping it will provide enough insight for you to adjust your own code)

```
import Foundation

let string = "ADOBECODEBANC"
let sub = "ABC"

//  Create a class to hold the start and end index of the current search range, as well as a remaining variable
//  that will store which characters from sub haven't been found
class Container {
    var start: Int
    var end: Int?

    var remaining: String

    //  Consume will attempt to find a given character within our remaining string, if it has found all of them,
    //  it will store the end index
    func consume(character: Character, at index: Int) {
        //  If remaining is empty, we're done
        guard remaining != "" else { return }
        //  We're assuming that sub won't have repeating characters. If it does we'll have to chage this
        remaining = remaining.replacingOccurrences(of: String(character), with: "")
        if remaining == "" {
            end = index
        }
    }

    init(start: Int, remaining: String) {
        self.start = start
        self.remaining = remaining
    }

}

//  ClosedContainer is similar to Container, but it can only be initialized by an existing container. If the existing
//  container doesn't have an end value, the initialization will fail and return nil. This way we can weed out containers
//  for ranges where we didn't find all characters.
class ClosedContainer {
    let start: Int
    let end: Int

    init?(container: Container) {
        guard let end = container.end else { return nil }
        self.start = container.start
        self.end = end
    }

    var length: Int {
        return end - start
    }
}

var containers = [Container]()

//  Go through each character of the string
string.enumerated().forEach { index, character in
    //  Look for matches in sub
    if sub.contains(character) {
        //  Allow each existing container to attempt to consume the character
        containers.forEach { container in
            container.consume(character: character, at: index)
        }
        //  Create a new container starting on this index. It's remaining value will be the sub string without the
        //  character we just found
        let container = Container(start: index, remaining: sub.replacingOccurrences(of: String(character), with: ""))
        containers.append(container)
    }
}

//  Convert Containers into ClosedContainers using compactMap, then find the one with the shortest length
let closedContainers = containers.compactMap(ClosedContainer.init)
let maybeShortest = closedContainers.min { $0.length < $1.length }
if let shortest = maybeShortest {
    //  Convert int to String indices
    let start = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: shortest.start)
    let end = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: shortest.end)
    //  Get the result string
    let result = string[start...end]
    print("Shortest substring of", string, "that contains", sub, "is", result)
} else {
    //  No range was found that had all characters in sub
    print(string, "doesn't contain all characters in", sub)
}
```